# Homework question: Let $\psi$ be a binary predicate. Prove ⊢ $(\forall x)(\forall y)\psi(x, y) \rightarrow (\forall y)\psi(y, y) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

[image: Rules and theorems]I know I can use deduction theorem to make the formula into: $(\forall x)(\forall y)\psi(x, y) ⊢ (\forall y)\psi(y, y)$ which can also be written as $(\forall x)(\forall y)\psi(x, y) \iff (\forall y)ψ(y, y)$. For my hypothesis, I can use the left-hand side:

1) $(\forall x)(\forall y)\psi(x, y)$ (hyp)

But I don't know how to proceed from the hypothesis to get the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, this should be pretty straightforward, since for $x$ and $y$ you just pick the very same object.  However, what an actual formal proof for this looks like depends on exactly what rules were given to you. Can you post those?

Comment: @Bram28 No rules were given other than to use a Hilbert style or equation proof. I posted a picture with some logic rules and such for some help.

Comment: Hmm, those are all propositional logic rules, and what you need here are rules involving quantifiers.  You weren't even given any example proofs?

Comment: @Bram28 Unfourtanetly not. Other than knowing the obvious which is the negation of ∀ or ∃ yields the opposite symbol.

Comment: Well, that stinks!  OK, I did post a proof as an Answer. It's a proof in the Fitch system ... not sure if that works for you ....

Comment: @Bram28 I'll take what I can get and verify it. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly, your textbook have also axioms and rules for quantifiers; otherwise how do you think to address problems with them ?

Comment: We need at least $(\forall x) A \to  A[x := t]$ (see page 139) followed by the **Generalization Th** (page 155).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
\forall x \forall y \ \psi(x,y)}{
\fitch{
a}{
\forall y \ \psi(a,y)\\
\psi(a,a)} \\ 
\forall y \ \psi(y,y)}$